# In Visual Studio Code, how can I configure terminal to show build errors in color?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-tasks

In Visual Studio Code 1.18.1, I have a build task:

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "Build LedaAP",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "c:/WindRiver/workbench-4/wrtool.bat -data c:/WindRiver/workspace_BR_SW_BFHW prj build LedaAP",
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "presentation": {
                "reveal": "always",
                "panel": "new"
            }
        }
}
```

The build output is in gcc style. Presently, all text is shown in black. How can I configure the terminal to show errors in red (or other highlight)?

Comment: I am surprised that errors aren't already shown in red.  But perhaps the "workbench.colorCustomizations"  : {  "errorForeground": "#f00" } will work for you.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but that did not work.  It seems that this feature is not fully supported yet: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/243

Comment: Did you try the extension https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=IBM.output-colorizer mentioned in that link? Just wondering if it works for you.

Comment: I have installed the Colorizer plugin (mentioned in the link) but there was no change in behaviour. I'm confused: it seems that tasks send output to the Output window and Colorizer operates on that window.  However, my build task is sending its output to the Terminal window.  Maybe that's why Colorizer is not having any effect. Is my task wrongly configured?